# Does .jss feature is not supported in Titanium mobile SDK

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I am trying to use .jss. but i dont know why it is not working. I have a mywindow.js file and i have created a `mywindow.jss` file.

in `mywindow.jss` file

```
#b 
{
 width: 40;
 height: 50;
 color: '#324f85';
 font: {fontFamily: 'Helvetica-Bold', fontSize: 15};
}
```

in `mywindow.js`

```
var myButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
id : "b",
title: 'clickME'

});
```

I dont know what i am doing wrong here.

Both .js and .jss file are in same location. Using sdk 1.8.1

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I am doing the same as you and it isn't for me...

Comment: @Adam it didnt work for me i tried to follow the kitchen sink code also but no +ve output... but now enjoy using Alloy framework.. :D

Comment: I read the docs, apparently .jss doesn't work well with CommonJS syntax

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you change (or create) any JSS classes, you need to clean your project before the style changes come through.

Titanium Menu bar > Project > Clean...

Comment: I think they are not supporting jss support I dont know about mobile web application dev..

Comment: Hi Ajeet, your comment doesn't make much sense in relation to my answer. Have you tried cleaning your project? Did it work or not?

Comment: Actually I am not using JSS now, I left it 7 months ago when I came to know that its not fully supported.

Answer (score 0):

yes it can be used, you can see the sample at [Kitchen sink](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/tree/master/Resources), its that people prefer to do it the normal way(coding both the UI & styles together) than with JSS

Comment: i referred kitchen sink app and still my code does not work..:(