# How Does .jss feature really works in Titanium mobile SDK?

Tags: android, android-layout, titanium, titanium-mobile

I found [this related question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496233/does-jss-feature-is-not-supported-in-titanium-mobile-sdk) and some other few blogs and Posts. None of them clarify how does this JSS thing really works....

What I am trying is to do a simple Implementation of JSS just to checkout how this thing works and implement it for various android devices.

**app.js**

```
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    className : "winodow"
});
user_window.open();
```

**-------------------------**

**app.android.jss**

```
.window {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

**This works perfectly fine but changing this to :**

**-------------------------**

**app.android.high.jss**

```
.window {
    background-color: #333;
}
```

**app.android.medium.jss**

```
.window {
    background-color: #666;
}
```

**app.android.low.jss**

```
.window {
    background-color: #999;
}
```

shows no affect for the window view.

Even declaring

which seems like they are not working in the desired way.

I am using titanium

```
<sdk-version>1.7.6.v20120320183239</sdk-version>
```

and simulator is

```
  Android-2.3.3, API Level 10, HVGA
```

Unable to find any clear documentation for implementation of JSS in titanium.

Unable to add new Tag **---JSS---**

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it was ever fully implemented. With the new [Alloy MVC](https://github.com/appcelerator/alloy) available, it is a moot point now.